# Terminal is not running any command after using command "cat > .bashrc"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, terminal

I was customizing my terminal by screenfetch. after installing screenfetch in my ubuntu, I have used some command

```
cat > .bashrc
# Start Screenfetch

screenfetch
```

then I pressed ctrl + d and closed the terminal. When I reopen the terminal now my terminal is showing an empty terminal.

The Terminal is not accepting any command and is showing nothing in it.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEM:**
.bashrc runs every time you open a bash shell. A single injection character ">" will overwrite the file. If you meant to append you need two of them `cat >> .bashrc`. If you have created a problem by editing, or overwriting, .bashrc then that problem will be encountered every time you run bash.

**SOLUTION:** You will need to restore a known good copy of .bashrc. Maybe you can edit it from a GUI text editor or copy a good one from a different user profile using your filesystem explorer. Some systems have a "skeleton" user that serves as a template for new user accounts. You can try to copy a default file for your system from the skeleton: `/etc/skel/.bashrc`

**WORKAROUND:**
If you need a Terminal try opening a different shell like ash, csh, ksh, sh or zsh.

Comment: Sure thing! Instead of commenting the custom is to select the answer and upvote it. That's all the thanks I need.

Comment: Copy the bashrc from `/etc/skel/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

**FOR UBUNTU USERS ONLY**

If anyone is still not able to solve this problem, then follow these steps:-

(1) open .bashrc

(2) remove all the content of .bashrc and copy these codes-

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

(3) save the file.

(4) open the terminal again.

Comment: This is not a solution fit for every OS. The OP said he was using Ubuntu and this is the .bashrc from Retropie, which is a Debian based OS made for the RaspberryPi that is optimized for video games. You should always use a known good .bashrc from your own system and not take this one. For example, the command `retropie_welcome` near the end will not exist on your system unless you are actually running RetroPie.